# Android LVL Signature Verification Failed

Tags: java, android, signature, verification, android-lvl

I am trying to implement the APK Expansion Downloader Library into my application, but I am struggling to get past the LVL verification check.

Everytime I run up the application, I get a "Signature verification failed" message back from the LicenseValidator class. The application is signed in release mode, with a proper Keystore.

I have checked maybe 10+ times that the PUBLIC_KEY I am using inside of the application is the same as on the developer account, yet its still not working. I have also uploaded the application to the Play Store, with the expansion file (correctly named), and even added in my account as a Test account on the developer console. I have also tried adding the publisher account onto my device, and its still not working.

I do not know what to do next, I need this to work and cannot find any help on the internet as to how to fix this.

Thanks

Adam

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you had several versions of file extansion? Because I had the same problem as the api sent me the name of an old file ... as a workaround in the verification code I just replaces the version number ... It's not terrible, but the bug does not come from me ...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Via "Manage apps" I stopped the Google Play Store app, cleared its data (not the cache, which was zero bytes), then restarted my licensed app - licensing now works.